# MonkeyTalk tests without internet

Tags: android, monkeytalk

Is it possible to test use cases where no network data is enabled?

```
adb shell svc data disable
```

I can connect to the app from MonkeyTalk IDE but it's not possible to record nor replay any test cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried this, but it seems very unlikely that it would work since the MonkeyTalk agent communicates with the script-running facility (e.g. the MonkeyTalkIDE, or junit, or the MonkeyTalk ant tasks) using HTTP. 
When running over USB, MonkeyTalk uses adb port forwarding. However, from the agent's point of view, it is still responding to HTTP requests over a TCP/IP port.

Comment: Ed, as you are from the staff of CloudMonkey, are planning to support this in a future release? I understand it would mean a change in the underlying architecture, right?

Comment: Right now network-free operation is not on our roadmap. Architecturally, it might be ok to operate over, say, USB vs. TCP/IP, since it's just a bunch of JSON packets. To operate as a standalone - i.e. with a device not connected to a separate "runner" computer - would mean running both the "runner" and the "agent" on the device. This might be feasible in Android, since (in theory) the Runner/Processor Java code might work there, and the JSON could (in theory) go over an IPC socket. In iOS the same strategy would require rewriting a chunk of stuff that is currently in Java into Objective-C.